# No option to create New Flutter Project on Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfYmo.png)

I've already installed Flutter and Dart in my plugins but I can't seem to find the wizard to create new flutter project

Comment: Have you set the plugins path correctly in android studio's settings?

Comment: https://ibb.co/fM6ZmJH still no luck, I've already made some troubleshooting like installing then restarting

Comment: have you download & install flutter sdk  @NeilDylandy?

Comment: Yep I've already downloaded and installed the flutter SDK

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8nzQEzV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to create a new flutter project open up the terminal and write inside of the folder where you want to create the project:

```
flutter create nameoftheproject
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/64VBcd8 I'm getting this error upon running

Comment: It seems that I didn't specify the root folder

Comment: try to run instead: flutter create nameoftheproject

Comment: this is not the subject of the topic

Answer (score 0):

For me, a recent update in the plugins disabled them in Android Studio last week. After updating Android Studio to BumbleBee (2021.1), the plugins enabled themselves again and I could create Flutter projects as usual.

The button to check for updates should be in

```
File --> Settings --> Appearance & Behavior --> System Settings --> Updates
```

Comment: For me, the `Project` view when manually opening an existing Flutter project also showed no highlighting of the `lib`folder etc, indicating that it wasn't working at all.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your instructions I did see the update but I'm still unable to see the "New Flutter Project" in the welcome page of Android Studio (I'm using the latest version)

Comment: A good-old `File --> Invalidate caches and Restart` might do the trick? Otherwise I'm not sure what causes your issue

Answer (score -1):

[image]

You must install to flutter from this page.

Comment: https://ibb.co/fM6ZmJH I've already installed that on my IDE

Comment: https://ibb.co/bJHyxkp

Comment: This worked in my case as well. The confusion here I believe is that before 1+ year this wasn't required (for Android Studio - was required for VS Code).